# /dev/video0: Invalid argument

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi4, hdmi, gopro, raspivid

we are trying to connect GoPro Hero 5 black to raspberri pi-4 using HDMI to CSI2 convertor.
but we are facing a problem, like whenever we try to stream using ffmpeg or any live video software we are unable to connect the device and it give the following error

> [video4linux2, v4l2 @ 0x15ce430] ioctl(VIDIOC_STREAMON):Invalid
> argument /dev/video0: Invalid argument

we tried

> cat /dev/video0
> throws the same error.

on the other hand we have the another camera which works perfectly!

Any inputs will be appreciable.

Comment: Is the camera detected? Try using `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` (requires the `v4l-utils` package)

Comment: it detects /dev/video0

Comment: i run the following command    "ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 /dev/video0" test.mkv"    its give the error as "Outpout file #0 doest not contain any stream"

Comment: you're missing an `-i` in your command, is that a typo? (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Webcam)

Comment: thanks but its typo!